# How to determine id date falls under one of the ranges (ranges are stored in separate rows of another table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have SalesFacts Table, which contains Sales_Amount, Customer_ID and Invoice_Date.
In another table I have Information's about special agreements for some of the customers (columns are: Customer_ID, Agreement_Start_Date, Agreement_End_Date).

Now - i would like to check, if the sales from SalesFact table occurred when special agreement was active for the Customer. This would be pretty easy, if there was only one date range when special agreement was active. However, in my case, Table with Special Agreements date ranges contains duplicated Customer ID, because for one Customer there might be several time ranges, where special agreement was active.

E.G. In SalesFact Table I have 3 transactions for one customer:

[image]

In SpacialAgreements Table I can see, that there are 2 data ranges when this customer had a right to special agreements.

[image]

I would like to create a query, that adds additional column to my SalesFacts table, that would determine, if the transaction happened when there was a Special Agreement Active. So in case shown above, it would be:

[image]

If there was Only one date range with special agreement it would be pretty easy:

```
Select
  S.[Sales_Amount], S.[Customer_ID], S.[Invoice_Date],
  IIF(S.[Invoice_Date] >= A.[Agreement_Start_Date] and S.[Invoice_Date]<=A.[Agreement_End_Date],'YES','NO') as AGREEMENT
  From SalesFacts S left join SpacialAgreements A on S.[Customer_ID] = A.[Customer_ID]
```

But since there are several date ranges in SpacialAgreement table, i don't know how to achieve that properly, without risking any duplicates in Sales_Amount and without loosing any data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get data exactly as you shown in question then for the SELECT statement you can use something like this:

```
SELECT 
        S.[Sales_Amount], 
        S.[Customer_ID], 
        S.[Invoice_Date],
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM SpacialAgreements A 
                          WHERE A.Customer_ID = S.Customer_ID 
                                AND S.[Invoice_Date] >= A.[Agreement_Start_Date] 
                                AND S.[Invoice_Date] <= A.[Agreement_End_Date])
             THEN 'YES'
             ELSE 'NO'
             END as Agreement
FROM SalesFacts S
```

So, this solution can be used if you are selecting data or creating view from this query.

If you want to have persisted value as one physical column in your SalesFacts table then you can try to solve your problem with triggers.